# I'm getting net.sf.JSONObject can't be cast to java.lang.String Exception

Tags: java, if-statement, json, getstring

I'm reading the `JSONObject` as input and i am retrieving the value of key "`id`" using `getString()` method of `net.sf.json` API but i'm curious to know why it is not going in the if block..

```
INPUT:
    {
    "id" : null
    }
```

code:

```
//reading the jsonObject from String
JSONObject jsonObject.fromObject(someString);
String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
if( id == null)
{
        //the control is not going in this if condition
}
```

Comment: print `id` value and see what it prints

Comment: you mean i need to use optString("id",null) instead of getString()

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject.fromObject(someString); is this code work??

Comment: it is printing null

Comment: where to use isNull()

Answer (score 0):

use `optString("id",null)` after `isNull()` check when you not sure about JSON format will be same and to handle `NPE`.

```
JSONObject jO=jsonObject.fromObject(someString);
String id = jO.optString("id",null);
if(jO.isNull("id"))
{
    //the control is not going in this if condition
}
else{

}
```

or

```
jsonObject.optJSONObjet(String arg1)
```

[read this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: can you tell me what this optString() will do and if i print the id value in this if block it prints "null"